# R paste vector values from list without c(...) and print to file

Tags: r, paste

I have two datasets, one containing a list of indices and the other containing a list of numbers.

```
v <- c("a", "b", "c", "d")

lst <- list(c("4", "75097", "72607", "72607", "62572"), NA, c("5", "113116", "5372", "5372", "11767"), c("4", "11767", "85822", "85822", "82080", "82080", "77055"))
```

I would like to print them side by side and feed the result into a `txt` file, with the following code:

```
connect <- file("new.txt")
writeLines(paste(v, lst, sep=" "), connect)
close(connect)
```

The result I get is this:

```
a c("4", "75097", "72607", "72607", "70692", "70692", "69112", "69112", "62572")
b NA
c c("5", "113116", "5372", "5372", "11767", "11767", "85822", "85822", "82080", "82080", "77055")
......
```

How do I print the vectorial strings on the `lst` without the `c(...)` to give this result?

```
a 4 75097 72607 72607 62572 
b NA 
c 5 113116 5372 5372 11767
d 4 11767 85822 85822 82080 82080 77055
```

Comment: You are `paste`ing vector with a `list`.  What is your expected output

Comment: Without the `c(..,..,..,..)`

Comment: Did you meant `Map(function(x, y) paste(x, paste(y, collapse=' '), sep= ' '), v, lst) %>% head`   BTW, there are some NA elements, how do you want to treat them?  If you want to ignore the NA `Map(function(x, y) if(all(is.na(y))) NA else paste(x, paste(y, collapse=' '), sep= ' '), v, lst)`

Comment: @akrun, I've simplified the data to make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` to `paste` the `list` elements with the corresponding elements of `vector`

```
out <- Map(function(x, y) paste(x, paste(y, collapse=' '), sep= ' '), v, lst)
```

---

Or use `sapply` to loop over the `list`, `paste` the contents together and then `paste` with the `vector`

```
out <- paste(v, sapply(lst, paste, collapse=' '))
```

For printing, we can use `cat`

```
cat(unlist(out, use.names = FALSE), sep="\n")
#a 4 75097 72607 72607 62572
#b 5 113116 5372 5372 11767
#c 4 11767 85822 85822 82080 82080 77055
#d 5 79414 79867 79867 80161 78893 79867 79867 80650 80650 80161
```

Comment: when I do the following code: `out <- Map(function(x, y) paste(x, paste(y, collapse=' '), sep= ' '), v, lst)`, `connect <- file("new.txt")
> writeLines(out, connect)`, I get the following error: 
`Error in writeLines(cdata, connect) : 'text' 引數不正確`

Comment: @Sati The `cdata` is still a `list`.  You need to `unlist(cdata)` and then write

Comment: Yes, you've just answered my question. Thank you!